# Aligning with symbol inside `\left...\rigth` brackets or parentheses

Tags: align, amsmath

I would like to align an equation on the equality sign with a symbol that is inside a `\left\{...\rigth\}` expression. Like this,

```
\begin{align*}
P \left \{ X &\in A \right \} \\
&= P \left \{ X_0 \in B \right \}
\end{align*}
```

But this produces an error "Missing \right.." and the right hand side *}* from the first line is not displayed.

> Why is this so, and is there a work around?

Comment: You cannot, they effectively hide the `&` from the align construction. Not in the example you give there is not reason at all to use left/right, here they don't scale and only makes your code harder to read. If you need a `&` inside `\{.... \} ` you'll need to use the manual scalers.

Comment: In general only use left/right when you really need them often they do nothing or end up being overly large.

Comment: I see, thanks! The example I gave here is simplified and in the real case the \left, \right do have effect on the size of the curly brackets { }.

Comment: What is "manual scalers"?

Comment: you can use `\bigl\{  x \bigr\}` (this is a duplicate)

Comment: `\bigl(\Bigl(\biggl(\Biggl(\Biggr)\biggr)\Bigr)\bigr)`, even though there is also `\big\Big...` it is best to add the l/r` to them